# Como fazer unescape com jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Estou montando uma página com ajax, ela tem uma modal de cadastro

Tenho um formulário que se encontra no arquivo `novo.php` e preciso fazer o include dele dentro da modal.

A modal é criada no instante que o usuario clica no botão de cadastro:

```
var inc = '<div class="modal"><p class="close_modal"></p><?="<?php include(\"View/Professor/novo.php\");?>"?></div>';
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cadastro').click(function(){
         $('article').prepend('<div class="dark"></div>');
         $('article').prepend(inc);
     });
});
```

O `prepend()` coloca o código php dentro da modal como eu quero, mas o jquery escapa o php

Ao abrir o console percebo que o jquery escreveu o php comentado:

```
<div class="modal">
   <p class"close_modal"></p>
   <!--<?php include("View/Professor/novo.php"); ?>-->
</div>
```

**Tem como escrever comando php dentro do Jquery sem que os mesmos sejam escapados?**

Comment: Essa string de `var inc` tem duas vezes a tag de abertura de PHP `<?`... acho que o problema é esse.

Comment: @Sergio a primeira tag de abertura é exclusiva de escrita, indica que tudo dentro dela será escrita na página. A segunda tag está dentro de uma string e não será executada, digo, será executada quando for escrita dentro da modal, mas o jquery está comentando ela

Comment: Já resolvi o problema usando o comando load() porém ainda assim gostaria de obter uma resolução para esse problema

Comment: Mas o jQuery não interpreta PHP... tudo o que é PHP e não fôr convertido no servidor vai ficar como texto no browser. O browser não lê PHP.

Comment: @Sergio visivelmente o jquery está escapando o PHP, comentou o trecho até em formato HTML

Comment: O que queres dizer com "está escapando o PHP"?

Comment: @Sergio utilizei o termo incorreto, 'escapar strings' é um processo diferente do qual eu descrevi. Dentro do meu script jquery coloquei um comando php para escrever um outro comando php dentro da página, o objetivo era fazer um include de outra arquivo, porém o  jquery proprio comentou o trecho de código php, uma visivel diretiva de segurança